# Eval command vs eval expression

Tags: splunk

It seems that there is a difference between eval *command* and eval *expression*:

*Eval command:*

```
eval velocity=distance/time
```

*Eval expression:*

```
stats count(eval(status=404)) AS status_count
```

Notice that in the case of the expression `eval` is used as a function with parentheses around the arguments. I found documentation for the eval command: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.3/SearchReference/Eval

Is there documentation for the eval expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you find something lacking in Splunk's documentation you should submit feedback on the relevant page (perhaps https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.3/SearchReference/Stats).  Splunk is excellent about updating their docs in response to user feedback.

The principal difference between `eval` as a command and `eval` as a function is the former assigns a value to a field (potentially also creating that field) whereas the latter returns a value to the outer function (there must always be an outer function).  Using `eval` with `stats` allows for more flexibility in what `stats` calculates.